# Add Css class depending on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a class to a set of divs depending on mouse position, the final outcome will be a wall of people looking at the cursor...

I've wrote something I believe should work and I can get to `addClass` but its very buggy and only seems to add the class once and not constantly check mouse position. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

```
this.setImageDirection = function(){
    if(mouseX >= this.imageLeft && mouseX <= this.imageRight && mouseY <= this.imageTop){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("up");
    } else if(mouseX < this.imageLeft && mouseY < this.imageTop){
      $(this).removeClass();
       $("."+this.className+">.head-image").addClass("up-left");
    } else if(mouseX <= this.imageLeft && mouseY >= this.imageTop && mouseY <= this.imageBottom){
        $(this).removeClass();
       $(this).addClass("left");
    } else if(mouseX < this.imageLeft && mouseY > this.imageBottom){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("down-left");
    } else if(mouseX >= this.imageLeft && mouseX <= this.imageRight && mouseY >= this.imageBottom){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("down");
    } else if(mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY > this.imageBottom){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("down-right");
    } else if(mouseX >= this.imageRight && mouseY >= this.imageTop && mouseY <= this.imageBottom){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("right");
    } else (mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY < this.imageTop){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("up-right");
    } 
};
```

**Working Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/cppsh7y9/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid. See this line:

```
} else (mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY < this.imageTop){
```

It should be:

```
} else if(mouseX > this.imageRight && mouseY < this.imageTop){
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference a jquery element with `$(this)`, but `this` is not an element, it is an instance of the `HeadImage` 'class', so the jquery methods aren't going to work. You'll want to save a reference to the element when you instantiate it, and add/remove the css class from that.

for example, maybe something like this:

```
function HeadImage(className){
   this.element = $('.' + className);
   this.className = className;
   /* rest of the function ... */
}
```

and then in the `setImageDirection` method:

```
this.setImageDirection = function(){
    if(mouseX >= this.imageLeft && mouseX <= this.imageRight && mouseY <= this.imageTop){
        this.element.removeClass();
        this.element.addClass("up");
    }
    /* ... */
}
```